# Haskell servant: Swagger description for MultiPart upload

Tags: haskell, swagger, servant

I am using servant-swagger to define a REST service and to generate a Swagger file from it. It uses an extended version of the [File upload combinator](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/133) to define a client for an endpoint to add a file. I'd like to add a Swagger description to the upload API. I would be happy if I could add a parameter like

```
{
  "in": "formData",
  "name": "file",
  "type": "file",
  "description": "File to upload"
}
```

to Swagger. Any idea how to do that? I was trying

```
instance HasSwagger api => HasSwagger (Files b :> api) where
  toSwagger _ = toSwagger (Proxy :: Proxy api)
    & allOperations.description .~ Just (Text.pack "Files description")
```

but that doesn't generate a description in the Swagger file (although it compiles).

Comment: what error messages do you get?

Comment: It does compile, but doesn't add a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with this:

```
instance HasSwagger api =>
         HasSwagger (Files b :> api) where
  toSwagger _ = toSwagger (Proxy :: Proxy api)
    & addParam param
    where
      param = mempty
        & name .~ "file"
        & required ?~ True
        & description ?~ "File to upload"
        & schema .~ ParamOther (mempty
            & in_ .~ ParamFormData
            & paramSchema .~ (mempty & type_ .~ SwaggerFile))
```